Choosing isolation resistor for Op-amp output
I want to choose an accurate value for an isolation resistor for my OP-AMP (OPA838).
Based on the datasheet, the OPA838 is very sensitive to capacitive loads and needs an isolation resistor added to ensure system stability. Without this resistor, there is a huge difference in the frequency response of the closed-loop system.

For choosing the isolation resistor value, the datasheet suggests this figure:

My questions are:

Is this  parameter the closed loop gain?

If yes, and if I have a different gain to that shown in the figure, how should I choose the isolation resistor? For example 60dB-> 1000 V/V?


My OPA838 configuration is a transimpedance amplifier and the loop gain is 60dB-> 1000 V/V, so I'm wondering how I choose the resistor value.


The trend of the graph suggests zero. I think your use of the word 'accurate' in the first paragraph is hopeful, a better word would be 'ballpark'.

What capacitive load you'll have in  your application?

Capacitive load is related to the track of my PCB and it is around 8-25 pF, depending on the length of the track. So, I do not have an exact value for this.

Calculate the isolation resistor Riso depending on the load capacitance Cload and the bandwidth of the TIA.
With given Cf = 33pF and Rf = 1k the TIA has a pole frequency at about fp = 4.823 MHz. Above fp the gain will decline. With an assumed Cload = 100pF and a RC filter cutoff frequency sufficiently above fp (e.g. 3 x fp) the isolation resistor should be Riso = 110 Ohm (e.g. 100 Ohm).

@ Raonoke, thank you for the helpful comment, so it means if the Cload is= 20pF, then the resistor values would be 530 Ohm, right?

Yes. In my example I chose a corner frequency that is a factor of 3 above the bandwidth of the TIA. Depending on your requirements you can go even higher (or lower).
